# .htaccess file: redirect localhost/sitelogin/profile/name to localhost/sitelogin/profile.php?username=name

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I have coded a lot of a website with html and php. I have made a user profile system, but I truly don't understand what I need to put in my .htaccess file to redirect "localhost/sitelogin/profile/name" to "localhost/sitelogin/profile.php?username=name" AND retain css information. profile.php contains `require '/includes/overall/oheader.php';` which contains `include 'includes/head.php';` which contains `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">`.

I would appreciate either direct help with this or a noob-friendly resource that I can look at for useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/sitelogin/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitelogin/

RewriteRule ^profile/([^./]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

For css/js paths fixing use this in your page's HTML `<head>` section:

```
<base href="/" />
```